# Compare DataFrames/csv and return only the columns that have differences including the Key value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two CSV file that I'm comparing and returning only the columns side by side that have different values.

```
df1
Country 1980    1981    1982    1983    1984
Bermuda 0.00793 0.00687 0.00727 0.00971 0.00752
Canada  9.6947  9.58952 9.20637 9.18989 9.78546
Greenland   0.00791 0.00746 0.00722 0.00505 0.00799
Mexico  3.72819 4.11969 4.33477 4.06414 4.18464

df2
Country 1980    1981    1982    1983    1984
Bermuda 0.77777 0.00687 0.00727 0.00971 0.00752
Canada  9.6947  9.58952 9.20637 9.18989 9.78546
Greenland   0.00791 0.00746 0.00722 0.00505 0.00799
Mexico  3.72819 4.11969 4.33477 4.06414 4.18464

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1=pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')



def diff_pd(df1, df2):
    """Identify differences between two pandas DataFrames"""
    assert (df1.columns == df2.columns).all(), \
        "DataFrame column names are different"
    if any(df1.dtypes != df2.dtypes):
        "Data Types are different, trying to convert"
        df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
    if df1.equals(df2):
        print("Dataframes are the same")
        return None
    else:
        # need to account for np.nan != np.nan returning True
        diff_mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
        ne_stacked = diff_mask.stack()
        changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
        changed.index.names = ['Country', 'Column']
        difference_locations = np.where(diff_mask)
        changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations][0]
        changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]
        y=pd.DataFrame({'From': changed_from, 'To': changed_to},
                            index=changed.index)
        print(y)
        return pd.DataFrame({'From': changed_from, 'To': changed_to},
                            index=changed.index)



diff_pd(df1,df2)
```

My current output is :

```
                   From       To
Country Column                  
0       1980    0.00793  0.77777
```

So instead of the index 0 I want to get the country name for the row that has the mismatched values. Below is a example.

I want my output to be:

```
                   From       To
Country Column                  
Bermuda  1980    0.00793  0.77777
```

Thank you to everyone that can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat shorter method that renames along the way:

```
def process_df(df):
    res = df.set_index('Country').stack()
    res.index.rename('Column', level=1, inplace=True)
    return res

df1 = process_df(df1)
df2 = process_df(df2)
mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
df3 = pd.concat([df1[mask], df2[mask]], axis=1).rename({0:'From', 1:'To'}, axis=1)
df3
                   From       To
Country Column                  
Bermuda 1980    0.00793  0.77777
```